Login failed for user identified principal
With the following code (context WPF .Net Core app) and a user properly created in the database CREATE USER [<user principal name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
I can login in the user to the Azure tenant (SignInButton_Click works) but GetInfoButton_Click fails with exception "Login Failed for user-identified Principal". I've checked all the obvious things (typos etc).
If I change Authentication to "Active Directory Interactive" then the GetInfo method proceeds, brings up the login screen and I can log the user in. So they're in the db.
I notice tracing through GetInfoButton_Click that conn.AccessToken is null after the using var conn... line. Is this the problem? How do I fix it? Do I need to specify something in scopes?
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;
using Microsoft.Identity.Client;    

public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    string[] scopes = new string[] {  };
    AuthenticationResult authResult = null;
    private async void SignInButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var app = App.PublicClientApp;
        
        ResultText.Text = string.Empty;
        TokenInfoText.Text = string.Empty;            

        var accounts = await app.GetAccountsAsync();
        var firstAccount = accounts.FirstOrDefault();
        try
        {
            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenSilent(scopes, firstAccount)
                .ExecuteAsync();
        }
        catch (MsalUiRequiredException ex)
        {
            authResult = await app.AcquireTokenInteractive(scopes).ExecuteAsync();
        }
        if (authResult != null)
        {
            TokenInfoText.Text = $"Access Token: {authResult.AccessToken}\nExpires On: {authResult.ExpiresOn}";
            ResultText.Text = authResult.Account.Username;
        }
    }

    private async void GetInfoButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string connectionString = @"Server=entraexperimentserver.database.windows.net,1433; Database = EntraExperiment3; Encrypt = True; TrustServerCertificate = True; Connection Timeout = 30; Authentication = Active Directory Default";
        using var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        {                
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("open!");
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}


If you fetch your own Access Token, you need to set it on the SqlConnection.AccessToken property.
Authentication = Active Directory Default asks the driver to fetch the access token for you.

I misunderstood. I thought the accesstoken in AuthenticationResult authresult provided by the login method would  be passed to SqlConnection. If I try to pass it manually, via conn.AccessToken = authResult.AccessToken (and remove the Authentication= Active Directory Default) and I add "https://database.windows.net//.default" to the scope, the connection opens. Frustrating thing is hours ago, I had tried both those things, but not at the same time...
